# Make HTTP Request from C# HttpClient to Same Machine using IP Address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

Basically, I need to be able to make an HTTP Request to a Website on the same machine I am on, without modifying the host file to create a pointer to the domain name.

For example.

I am running the code on one website, let's say www.bobsoft.com which is on a server.

I need to make an HTTP request to www.tedsoft.com which is on the same server.

**How can I make a call using a C# HttpClient without modifying the host file?**  Take into account that the websites are routed by bindings in IIS.  I do know the domain I am going to use ahead of time, I just have to make it all internal in the code without server changes.

Thanks!

Comment: Website routed by IIS bindings - are they all on the same port but bound to different hostnames?

Comment: So, why not just do the request to `www.tedsoft.com`?

Comment: You have not explained what is stopping you from just using the host name?  What happens when you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS bindings on the same port but different hostnames are routed based on the http [`Host` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host). The best solution here is really to configure local DNS so requests made to `www.tedsoft.com` don't leave the machine. That being said, if these kinds of configuration aren't an option you can easily set the host header as a part of your `HttpRequestMessage`.

I have 2 test sites configured on IIS.

- Default Web Site - returns text "test1"
- Default Web Site 2 - returns text "test2"

[image: IIS Website Configurations]

The following code uses `http://127.0.0.1` (`http://localhost` also works) and sets the host header appropriately based on the IIS bindings to get the result you're looking for.

```
class Program
{
    static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test1 = GetContentFromHost("test1"); // gets content from Default Web Site - "test1"
        string test2 = GetContentFromHost("test2"); // gets content from Default Web Site 2 - "test2"
    }

    static string GetContentFromHost(string host)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://127.0.0.1");
        msg.Headers.Add("Host", host);

        return httpClient.SendAsync(msg).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```